# PHPUnit & Selenium - after updating to 3.6.10 version it seems that markTestSkipped and markTestIncomplete calls lead to have an error the test

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

In PHPUnit 3.6.4, when I run a test based on PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase, and I use

```
$this->markTestSkipped();
```

or

```
$this->markTestIncomplete();
```

I have the test skipped (S) or marked as incomplete (I).

But after updating PHPUnit to 3.6.10 - the latest now - these functions seem to fail the test by producing an error instead of skipping it.

More examples, take this test:

```
class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    public function testMyCase()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete();
    }
}
```

It will still run the test and give you this output, if you don't have Selenium server running:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.25Mb

There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testMyCase
RuntimeException: 

/usr/bin/phpunit:46

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1
```

If you do have Selenium server running you result will be slightly different but you will still have an error. This is for Selenium tests only, tests extending PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase seems to be ok. To confirm that, change the class you are extending it from to PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase:

```
class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testMyCase()
    {
        $this->markTestIncomplete();
    }
}
```

And you will have this result:

```
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

I

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 5.25Mb

OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Incomplete: 1.
```

So my question is: is this a bug in PHPUnit 3.6.10? Is this some cool feature I don't know and I am doing something wrong?

Comment: There are probably some bugs with this version of PHPUnit. I had got also problems: I received errors that some 'assert...' methods are not defined, but while testing with PHPUnit 3.5 there was everything all right. I had came back to older version of PHPUnit by downgrading it (http://www.niden.net/2012/01/downgrading-phpunit-from-36-to-35.html).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and it looks like that this issue is not tied to PHPUnit's core but rather to the PHPUnit Selenium extension. [A ticket has already been filed in their issue tracking system](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/127).

I tracked down the exact line where the error is thrown and found it in [Extensions/SeleniumTestcase.php on line 1215](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/020a51fb248ed2c4f02a428fa1a78f48fdba08d6/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php#L1215):

```
1213: // gain the screenshot path, lose the stack trace
1214: if ($this->captureScreenshotOnFailure) {
1215:    throw new PHPUnit_Framework_Error($buffer, $e->getCode(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine(), $e->getTrace());
1216: }
```

As you can see, this error occurs only if `$this->captureScreenshotOnFailure` is set to true. So the workaround I am currently using is to set `$this->captureScreenshotOnFailure=true` in the `setUp()` method of my Selenium tests and in each test that is marked as skipped I disable the screenshots manually before calling the skip method:

```
public function setUp() {
    [...]
    $this->captureScreenshotOnFailure = true;
}
```

---

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function mySkippedTest() {
    $this->captureScreenshotOnFailure = false; 
    $this->markTestSkipped(); 
    [...]
}
```

This works for me as it correctly marks skipped Selenium tests as such but still retains the screenshot feature for all the other tests.

However, if you have a huge number of skipped tests in your projects this might be a bit tedious to do and I can't guarantee that there aren't any other side effects, as I'm not all too familiar with PHPUnit's internals. In this case probably the best solution would be to wait with the update until it is fixed by the creators of phpunit-selenium as it seems that they are already aware of this issue.